# CakePHP, how can I find all products associated with sub categories when parent category given?

Tags: cakephp, tree, parent-child

I've got two tables that are setup to use the tree behavior, manufacturers, and categories.

Products can only belong to one category and only one manufacturer, however some manufacturers(child) are owned by other manufacturers(parent), and likewise some categories(child) are a subcategory of another(parent).

I want to do the following:

given a category id (parent), find all products in subcategories
given a manufacturer id (parent), find all products in child manufacturers

I have tried the following (in products controller):

```
$conditions['Product.category_id'] = $this->Product->Category->children($id,false,'id');
$this->paginate = array(
            'conditions' => $conditions,
            'limit' => 21
        );
$products = $this->paginate('Product');
$this->set(compact('products'));
```

but it gives me this:

```
 WHERE `Product`.`category_id` IN (Array, Array, Array, Array, Array, Array)
```

**if I do a print_r I can see it is grabbing the information I need(see below), but how can I get to it, and is there better way to do this?**

```
Array
(
[Product.category_id] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Category] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 11
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [Category] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 12
                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [Category] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 23
                    )

            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [Category] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 24
                    )

            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [Category] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 25
                    )

            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [Category] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 26
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query is failing because it expects an array containing *only* the category-ids, like this:

```
$conditions['Product.category_id'] = array(1,4,5,6);
```

You can achieve this by 'extracting' those values from your array using `Hash::extract()` (or `Set::extract()` if you're using CakePHP 1.3)

```
$categoryIds = $this->Product->Category->children($id,false,'id');

$conditions['Product.category_id'] = Hash::extract($categoryIds, '{n}.Category.id);
```

Read the documentation on the Hash Utility here:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html#Hash::extract

Comment: Thanks thaJeztah,  this is definitely what I was looking for.  Is this best practices when getting products associated with child categories? or is there a better way?  I have a feeling I will be using it quite often, and want to make sure I am doing it the right way.

Comment: I think this is a nice approach. To make this more re-usable, it's probably best to create a method on your Model, e.g. `Product::findProductsInCategory($categoryId)`. For performance, caching is always an option, but start with creating the right indexes in your database.

Comment: Glad I could help. Good luck with your project!

Comment: I can't believe that I was banging my head on wall all day because I was typing `Hash::extarct(...)` instead of `Hash::extract(...)`... I just copied and pasted out of frustration and it worked... SublimeText should have suggested the spelling error... +1 i was about to jump off the roof... Now, I guess I really should...

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr haha, I gues we've all been there one way or another. Glad you figured it out :-)